# I am using linq statement to update data in database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, linq

I am using LINQ statement to update data in database. First user will search for name and the details will be displayed in gridview and then user will select one employee and the data will be displayed in the relative textbox and dropdownlist.

When I select data in both dropdown it works fine and the database gets updated and if I select only one dropdown it shows error

> "The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_Emp_Location". The conflict occurred in database "EmpDept", table
>   "dbo.Location", column 'LocationID'."

//Update Button

```
using (DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext())
{
    Emp employee = dc.Emps.Single(emp => emp.EmpID == id);
    employee.EmpFirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
    employee.EmpLastName = txtLastName.Text;
    employee.MgrID = int.Parse(txtMgrID.Text);
    employee.BirthDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDOB.Text);
    employee.Email = txtEmail.Text;
    employee.Mobile = txtMobile.Text;
    employee.LocationID = ddlLocation.SelectedIndex;
    employee.Salary = int.Parse(txtSalary.Text);
    employee.DeptID = ddlDepartment.SelectedIndex;
    //dc.Emps.InsertOnSubmit(employee);
    dc.SubmitChanges();

    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Record Updated Successfully!!!')", true);
    clearFields();
}
```

//Grid View

```
    protected void gvSearch_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ddlDepartment.Items.RemoveAt(0);
            ddlLocation.Items.RemoveAt(0);

            string ddlDept = gvSearch.SelectedRow.Cells[9].Text;
            string ddlLoc = gvSearch.SelectedRow.Cells[10].Text;

            ListItem deptRemove = ddlDepartment.Items.FindByText(ddlDept);
            ddlDepartment.Items.Remove(deptRemove);
            ListItem locRemove = ddlLocation.Items.FindByText(ddlLoc);
            ddlLocation.Items.Remove(locRemove);

            txtEmpID.Text = gvSearch.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
            txtFirstName.Text = gvSearch.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
            txtLastName.Text = gvSearch.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;
            txtMgrID.Text = gvSearch.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text;
            txtDOB.Text = gvSearch.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text;
            txtEmail.Text = gvSearch.SelectedRow.Cells[6].Text;
            txtMobile.Text = gvSearch.SelectedRow.Cells[7].Text;
            txtSalary.Text = gvSearch.SelectedRow.Cells[8].Text;
            ddlDepartment.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(ddlDept));
            ddlLocation.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(ddlLoc));

        }
        catch
        { 

        }
    }
```

//DropDownList

```
 private void BindDDL()
    {
        try
        {
            using (DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext())
            {
                var location = from l in dc.Locations
                          select l;
                ddlLocation.DataSource = location;
                ddlLocation.DataValueField = "LocationID";
                ddlLocation.DataTextField = "LocationName";
                ddlLocation.DataBind();
                ddlLocation.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Location--"));

                var department = from d in dc.Depts
                          select d;
                ddlDepartment.DataSource = department;
                ddlDepartment.DataValueField = "DeptID";
                ddlDepartment.DataTextField = "DeptName";
                ddlDepartment.DataBind();
                ddlDepartment.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Department--"));
            }
        }
```

[image: Database]
[image: Error after changing SelectedIndex to SelectedValue]

[image]
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

You have used the [`SelectedIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx), instead use the [`SelectedValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
employee.LocationID = int.Parse(ddlLocation.SelectedValue);
```

same applies to the department:

```
employee.DeptID = int.Parse(ddlDepartment.SelectedValue);
```

You're lucky that there was no ID matching the selected-index, so you get this error instead of inconsistencies. Another reason why foreign-key constraints are useful.

Comment: same gose for departmentid

Comment: I have changed that to SelectedValue and got error "FormatException was unhandled".

Comment: I have added DropDownList Code and Database Image also.

Comment: try to add EnableViewState="true" to your DropDownList of locations